# How to make auto generated id function?

Tags: vb.net, function, module

I try to create a function for generate the id in sql table. but i don't know how to set parameter for select table and columns please help me

```
Public Function autoid(ByVal col As String, ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal tb As String)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim id As Integer
    cn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT MAX('" & col & "') FROM '" & tb & "' "

    Try
        If IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar) Then

            id = 1
            txt.Text = id
        Else
            id = cmd.ExecuteScalar + 1
            txt.Text = id

        End If
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
```

it show this error `Incorect syntax near ..my tb value ..`

Comment: what database are you using?  Most will create a unique ID automatically

Comment: Look into scope identity... if sql, set column auto generate and seed to 1

Comment: I use sql server 2012 .

Comment: you don't want single quotes around the table (tb) or your column (col). that is most likely the reason for your error. also, what are your intentions with this function? what will you use it for?

Comment: want to it to generate id in textbox for inert into database auto. by set col as the colums name and tb as name of table.

Answer (score 0):

Download mssql management studio attach your database locally setup autorincrement on your field which require unique id set it be not nullable field and that's all mssql 2012 make al the rest for you.